python terraform destroy auto approve not working
I have a python code that performs terraform plan, apply and destroy.
Terraform plan and apply work fine, but destroy crashes with error
Error: Failed to parse command-line flags
flag provided but not defined: -force
For more help on using this command, run:
terraform destroy -help
from python_terraform import *
t = Terraform()
tf = Terraform(working_dir="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/TerraformProject")
tf.init()
print('terra init completed')
#return_code, stdout, stderr = tf.init(capture_output=False)
plans=tf.plan()
print('terra plan completed')
#return_code, stdout, stderr = tf.plan(capture_output=False)
tf.apply(no_color=IsFlagged, skip_plan=True)
#return_code, stdout, stderr = tf.apply(capture_output=False)
print('terra apply is complited')
tf.destroy(force=IsFlagged, no_color=IsFlagged,   dir_or_plan="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/TerraformProject")
return_code, stdout, stderr = tf.destroy(capture_output=False)

Can you help me resolve an issuie ?

The destroy -force flag is deprecated, so you can use:
tf.destroy(no_color=IsFlagged, force=IsNotFlagged, auto_approve=True, dir_or_plan="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/TerraformProject")

See also https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform/issues/108
